# Como a função 'parseFloat()' funciona?

Tags: javascript

Eu queria que alguém me explicasse como funciona essa função. Por exemplo:

Qual a diferença de:

```
  var valor1 = 50;
  var valor2 = 40;
  var result = valor1 + valor2
```

Para:

```
  var valor1 = 50;
  var valor2 = 40;
  var result = parseFloat(valor1) + parseFloat(valor2);
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

No exemplo que você deu, o parseFloat não está fazendo nada, pois você está passando valores inteiros pra dentro dela.

Ela serve para converter *string* em um valor de número com ponto flutuante (casas após a virgula em português, no caso do javascript o ponto).

Por exemplo:

```
var valorStr = '50.5';
var parseValorStr = parseFloat(valorStr);
typeof valorStr // string
typeof parseValorStr // number
```

Se você vai trabalhar com valores inteiros pode utilizar o `parseInt`, porém se a string que você está convertendo tiver um valor decimal, ele vai remover este valor.

```
parseInt('50.5'); // 50
```

Como o Javascript trabalha com tipagem fraca, também é possível converter um valor numérico dentro de uma string apenas usando um operador matemático, por exemplo:

```
var valor = '50.5';
typeof +valor // Number (neste caso 50.5)
```

Porém se na sua string contém caracteres alfabéticos, é importante o uso de `parseFloat` ou `parseInt` para manter a integridade da aplicação, pois se usar o + em uma string que contenha caracteres não numéricos, ele vai concatenar os valores e não soma-los.

Exemplo:

```
+'50.5' + 50; // 100.5
'50.5' + 50; // 50.550
parseFloat('50.5') + 50; // 100.5
parseInt('50.5') + 50; // 100
parseFloat('50.5a') + 50; // 100.5
'50.5a' + 50; // 50.5a50
+'50.5a' + 50; // NaN
```

No último caso onde eu tento adicionar uma operação matemática na string `'50.5a'` o javascript tenta converter para um valor numérico mas quando encontra a letra `a` ele interrompe a operação e retorna um valor que identifica como Não é um Número (`NaN`, Not a Number).

Comment: Você poderia editar sua reposta mostrando um exemplo funcional dele em uma operação matemática.

Comment: @SamirBraga adicionei exemplos :)

Comment: Muito Obrigado mesmo, agora fivou claro.

Comment: Muito boa explicação! Gabriel.

Comment: show de bola. a melhor explicação sobre esses erros que ocorrem que eu encontrei